# Android devices not recognized in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, android

I'm trying to set up my app development environment and have hit a snag. When I connect an Android device to my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, it is not recognized in any way. It starts charging, but I don't get any popups asking me to connect or mount it. This is happening with two different devices (Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus and Lenovo Yoga Book) and multiple USB cables.

When I run `lsusb` it does not show any Android devices. I have connected to every USB port on the laptop and none of them are working.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable SoftSailing
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b270 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I created an Android rules file with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"dev
```

I've edited `/etc/fuse.conf`

```
# /etc/fuse.conf - Configuration file for Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)

# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.
#mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.
user_allow_other
```

I've turned on developer options and enabled USB debugging on both. My user is part of the `plugdev` user group.

`adb devices` is empty.

I've already rebooted a few times.

These are all of the steps I have found when searching online. Nothing has resolved the issue so far.

I don't know what the next step is. Does anyone have a suggestion?

**Edit to Add**

When viewing the system logs, if I connect a different USB device, such as a headset, I see a lot of activity in the system log. When I connect an Android device, nothing happens in the logs. It's like it just doesn't detect anything at all. I don't understand this.

**Edit to Add 2**

Okay, so I figured out what was wrong and it was really silly. I forgot that I had a charging case on my phone. Apparently you can transfer data through the pass-through port on the charging case. After removing the case, I can connect my Samsung phone. The other two tablets still don't connect, but they use a different USB cable, so maybe there is an issue with that cable. That was really frustrating!

Comment: Please use the usbs that came with the phones  I noticed it will only show up when done this way,

Comment: I'm using the USB cable that came with the phone.

Comment: If you worked out what your problem was, please consider writing an answer to your own question and accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting about a half a day trying to figure out why this wouldn't work, I realized the problem with my Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus was that I was using a charging case. The pass-though port on the charging case doesn't support data transfer, so I need to remove it when I am connecting to the computer.

As for the other devices, I assume there is an issue with the cable I was using to connect then, but I haven't tested that yet.

Answer (score 3):

Chiming in with somewhat similar experience: The issue was [a cable](http://www.dx.com/p/mini-smile-3-4a-type-c-to-usb-2-0-charging-data-cable-1m-blue-467703#.WfBuRXVL-90) I bought from dx.com. It charged but it wouldn't connect data. Even weirder is that it worked in Windows 10.

A *micro-USB* with a micro-to-C-adapter worked though! Also bought from China

tl;dr: Try different cables, preferrably the original one (I've lost it)